# Telethon events.NewMessage() doesn't work after a few hours

Tags: python, telethon

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

client = TelegramClient('zjy', 29155464, '64f8ebfa27060b5c62b585910547e1da')


@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)


client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

this is the code,and problem is that i can constantly print new messages..but after a few hours,the program seems stuck and suspend and can't print new message any more,and when i press Enter on my keyboard it prints the new message before immediately...... how to solve this issue?

Comment: well, as per the code `run_until_disconnected()`,  if you have been disconnected (for whatever reason), it will stop running.  So you would need to add a method to restart.

Comment: This seems like a bug in the library. Please make sure you are using the latest version. if you are and the issue still occurs, be sure to check the project's issue board on GitHub, and make a new issue if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @keramat StackOverflow is a place for questions, not to report bugs for libraries. As I stated previously, please check the project's issue board on GitHub.

Comment: Yes, I checked and could not find any related issue. If I missed please let me know the issue id. If there is not I can create one.